# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded

Tags: spring, spring-shell

I am using below dependencies in my spring boot shell application.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

But When I am trying to run the application, I am getting error like **'ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded'**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can u please add full pom.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with these dependencies.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1</version>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


</project>
```